# A count's aunt goes to auditory specialist because of hearing issues [10], cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues, english

A single cryptic type cross word clue...

> A count's aunt goes to auditory specialist because of hearing issues. [10]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reckon this may be

> accountant

because it

> sounds like (hearing issues) 'a count('s) aunt', and they are a specialist in auditing.

Comment: Wow, nice one. Auditory specialist, lol

Comment: Nal fvtavsvpnapr gb *urnevat* "vffhrf" nf "FH"?

Comment: @RayButterworth no!